# Задать цвет для строк UIPickerView

Tags: xcode, swift3, mobile-development

Есть PickerView где все строки черные. Нужно поменять их цвет на белый, например.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы добиться требуемого Вам результата Вы можете определить свой   делегат для `UIPickerView`, в нём Вам надо будет определить метод `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:`. Кроме этого Вам следует добавить ещё и свой источник данных (если у Вас его раньше не было). То есть у Вас получится примерно следующее (код на языке Swift 3.3):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.pickerView.delegate = self
        self.pickerView.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

Источник данных:

```
extension ViewController : UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        return 10
    }
}
```

Делегат для вашего `UIPickerView`:

```
extension ViewController : UIPickerViewDelegate {

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

        let rootView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        let textLabel = UILabel.init(frame: rootView.frame)
        textLabel.text = "Ваш текст"
        textLabel.textColor = UIColor.yellow // Любой цвет текста, например жёлтый
        rootView.addSubview(textLabel)
        rootView.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown // Любой цвет фона, например коричневый
        return rootView
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасбио! Я сделал, но по-другому.